# Counting Number of Items in a tuple List in Erlang

Tags: erlang

I have the following List structure:

```
[{A, [{B <--, [A, C]}, {C <--, [B, A]}]}, {B, [{C <--, [A, C]}]}]
```

For example, `B = 1`, `C = 2`.

What would be the correct way to do so?

**UPDATE**

I'd like to count the number of `<--` (a symbol I added just to show what I'm referring to) pointed item in it.

Comment: Would you mind to elaborate? What's the meaning for this `<--` symbol in your question? Do you want to know how many values/items a list (that may contain tuples) can have?

Comment: @ɐuıɥɔɐɯ hi, <-- is just a symbol I added to show items I wanted to count

Answer (score 2):

It can be implemented in many ways. Here is one more.

```
 count(List) ->
    count(List, dict:new()).

count([{_, InList} | Rest], Dict) ->
    count(Rest, count2(InList, Dict));
count([], Dict) ->
    dict:to_list(Dict).

count2([{Symbol, _} | Rest], Dict) ->
    count2(Rest, dict:update_counter(Symbol, 1, Dict));
count2([], Dict) ->
    Dict.
```

Example Output:

```
1> test:count([{one, [{b, [123]}, {c,[123]}, {b,[123]}]}, {two, [{b, [123]}, {c,[123]}, {b,[123]}]}]).
[{b,4},{c,2}]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write a simple code using an accumulator and some list functions. Supposing all list elements are of the same format:

```
count(L) ->
    count (L, []).

count ([], Cases) ->
    Cases;
count ([{_E1, [{X, [_E2, _E3]}]} | Rest], Cases) ->
    NewCases =
        case lists:keysearch(X, 1, Cases) of
            false ->
                [ {X, 1} | Cases ];
            {value, {X, Val}} ->
                lists:keyreplace(X, 1, Cases, {X, 1+Val})
        end,
    count(Rest, NewCases).
```